# I want to "save" the model to run the validations, but not write it into the database

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have been searching for a solution on how to do this, but the closest I have come to a solution is in your model, have

```
public function beforeSave() {
    parent::beforeSave();

    if(!isset($this->data["Model"]["confirm"])) {
        return false;
    }
   }
```

And in the controller simply do:

```
        $this->Model->save($this->request->data);
        if($this->Model->validates()) {
            $this->render("confirm");
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The model could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            // now we can render
            $this->render("index");
        }
```

The problem with this approach is that it will display the error message twice, is there a better way to do this? Or should I do this the hackish way and find a way to remove the error message that is displayed twice.

Comment: documetionation covers this http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1182/Validating-Data-from-the-Controller

Comment: @dm03514 I'm using Cakephp 2.x, is there anything I should keep in mind while reading a 1.3 documentation?

Comment: yes sorry let me check if documentation is relevant. model should have a `validates()` function though.

Comment: @dm03514 Nvm found the relavent page: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should of looked into the documentation a bit deeper: the answer lies in http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html

Thanks to @dm03514 for pointing me to look at the documentation rather than the API (which I have read for days without finding a real answer)!